# cd command does not see the directory in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
run_python(){
    cd "`dirname $1`"
    python "`basename $1`" $2 >test.log
}

crypto_util=/home/dev/src/crypto/util.py
run_python $crypto_util "testpassword"
```

Somehow cd command fails saying:

cd: /home/dev/src/crypto No such file or directory. I am quite sure the directory exists.

On a side note if I do the following this fails too:

```
run_python(){
    python "$1" $2 >test.log
}
```

Saying python can not open the file `/home/dev/src/crypto/util.py` because there is no such file.

Any idea why?

Here is the output of the ll command on the directory/file:

```
drwxr--r--. 2 dev root 4096 Jun 11 18:56 crypto

-rwxr--r--. 1 dev root  4934 Jun  9 10:50 util.py
```

Output of ls -llid /home/

```
654084 drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4096 May  8 10:52 /home
```

Output of ls -lid /home/dev/

```
924265 drwxr--r--. 4 dev root 4096 Jun  9 09:17 /home/dev/
```

Output of ls -lid/home/dev/src/:

```
924266 drwxr--r--. 9 dev root 4096 Jun  9 10:01 /home/dev/src/
```

Output of ls -lid/home/dev/src/crypto:

```
924333 drwxr--r--. 2 dev root 4096 Jun 11 18:56 /home/dev/src/crypto/
```

Output of ls -lid/home/dev/src/crypto/util.py:

```
924337 -rwxr--r--. 1 dev root 4934 Jun  9 10:50 /home/dev/src/crypto/util.py
```

Comment: Can you do an ls of /home/dev/src/crypto and post the output?

Comment: @Jake I don't think so. In the other question the poster thought it wasn't working, but it was. Here, the poster is actually getting an error. I'm wondering if the directory permissions are wrong, preventing directory traversal.

Comment: What is the output of your `id` (or `id -a`) command.  Are you running as user `dev`?  Are you a member of group `root`?  What happens when you run `cd /home/dev/src/crypto`?

Comment: @JakeGould CentOS 6.4

Comment: Can you include the output of running `bash -x` on that script, just to confirm whats being run?  This will display each command prior to it being run, and will likely still fail.  When it does, could you also try running these commands in your interactive shell to double check they have a chance of working?

Comment: The output of `ls -lid / /home /home/dev /home/dev/src /home/dev/src/crypto /home/dev/src/crypto/util.py` (plus confirmation of whether you are the owner or belong to any of the groups of any of the files or directories) might be of interest.  If there's a symlink anywhere, then chasing the symlink would help (but let's cross that bridge when we get to it).

Comment: Why are the file names missing from the `ls` outputs?  You'd be more convincing if you copied and pasted the command line (singular) and the outputs. You've got spacing errors in your latest update.  Separately, I've found mention of SE Linux on the Centos web site (roughly, it says "Don't disable IPv6 because it might upset SE Linux if you do that"). So there are likely to be ACLs and related topics to consider. The directory permissions are wonky all the way up the hierarchy that you've shown (and you haven't shown the uppermost levels -- they're important too!). Try adding the group x-perm.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks! Updated. I am copying from my vm which surprisingly does no work via vnc.

Comment: @Jon ACLs seem the most likely culprit, but it's odd that he can do an ls, which implies read/execute permission, but not cd. Can he have an ACL like that?

Comment: @CDahn: I'm not sure what's going on, yet.  I don't think ACLs can allow you to do `ls -l` on a file indicating read and execute and yet not be able to handle it.  I am unsure what the `.` means, but it is probably the innocuous 'there is no ACL', but I'd rather have concrete confirmation of that.  (On Mac OS X, that column is blank when there's nothing special.)  I note that the permissions were changed, but we still don't know the details of the ID (there was mention of `dev` and `root`, but groups aren't clear).  It's all a bit vague…

Answer (score 2):

some of those dirs don't have x permission bit set - those are needed for entering a directory. Your problem may be that your scripts are running with another user as owner than "dev". dev is the only user allowed to change to those directories.
Set the dirs to +x, and try again.

Comment: Not having my computer handy to try, some searching determined that you can ls without the execute bit set. So, this seems like the most likely explanation. If @Arunav posts the output of the id command, that'll definitely confirm it.